# How much can a system administrator see?

Tags: ssh, system-preferences

I have Cygwin installed on a Windows system. From Cygwin I SSH into some other system that is not part of the network.

Does the system administrator know that I am connected to this remote system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, he does. He can see the IP you're connected to, he can see you're using port 22 (unless you've configured SSH to use a different port), and deduce you're using SSH.

There are ways to mask your activity and endpoint IP from a local admin, like proxy servers, TOR etc.

Comment: @JakeGould agree with 100% potential, don't agree that admins are clueless. They're as clueless as their job requires them to be. There are enough tools out there that can monitor traffic automatically, and alert you to irregularities, or potentially criminal behavior. But if no one in the org cares, and the admin gets that notion, they stop caring as well.

Answer (score 1):

A system administrator has the *potential ability* to see and log 100% of all activity that comes through their system. Which makes it seem like you are being watched at all times. But in many practical cases, systems administrators only see what they want to see. Meaning that if they don’t proactively pay attention to logs or have tools in place to alert them about activity, the presence of a user could be taken as “invisible.”

For example, even the laziest systems administrator would be able to see a login from you as well as a basic IP address from a simple remote access.  On a Linux system just type in `last` to see a huge list of the “last” users who have logged into the system.

But then as far as user activity goes, that is a crapshoot. Files like `.bash_history` keep a running history of commands one enters from the `bash` shell. So if there was a login by you in the last few days and the systems administrator copied the `.bash_history`, they could deduce what you did to a point. But `.bash_history` still only tells you so much. And heck, it’s a simple text file. So if you wanted to you could erase that manually without special privileges and erase your trail of `bash` activity. But this is all a big pile of “ifs.”

The reason I am stating this is if all systems administrators proactively saw everything at all times, then there would be no security breaches or cyber-crime, right? Yet despite technology getting better and tools getting better it seems like more and more systems are breached every day.

The way you should look at this is basically the same way you should look at the Internet in general: While digital media provides the potential to have copies of everything in the world accessible to everyone at all time, the reality is neglect and ignorance makes things “disappear.” For example, a website created in the 1990s might still be around if a systems administrator had the foresight to archive data. But 9 times out of 10, systems will die, fail or be obsoleted, old data becomes unreadable or media is erased for resale and suddenly digital data that has the potential to last forever vanishes like “magic.”

Which is all to say is unless you know otherwise, assume your activity is being monitored. But my practical experience seeing—and cleaning up—the messes left by sloppy systems administrators shows me that most system administrators are proactively clueless to what happens on their own systems and mange their systems in a reactive, “Oh crap! What happened now!” basis.

Comment: I'd upvote this if I could.